# Can someone help me solve this word problem on vector and magnitude?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

> A river is 2000 feet wide and flowing at 6mph from north to south. A guy in a boat starts on the east shore and heads west at a normal paddling speed of 2mph. In what direction (measured clockwise from the north) will he actually be traveling? And how far downstream from a point directly across the river will he land?

---

My attempt:

I am having trouble solving this problem. I don't know how to start; like what steps should I take? how I can go to through it, including how you got the answer. I basically would like a walkthrough of the problem. I'm brushing up on my math skills. It's been a long while and I'm really bad at understanding vectors and magnitude.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? And how do you want your direction measured? In degrees?

Comment: The problem didn't specify. And I'm not a good artist.

Comment: @miiworld2: He was not asking for _art_, just for a diagram of the situation. The first step for such geometric problems is to draw a diagram.

Comment: I don't care for ART. I care about the PROBLEM. And I know about the first step already from class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a sketch really fast. (I forgot to add north, but north is upwards. The flow is southwards and hence is draw with a vector that has a downwards direction in the sketch) [image: Sketch of the river and forces in play]

Adding the paddlingvector and the flowvector gives us the directionvector in which the person moves. This holds by the parrallelogramrule for vectors or basis vectoraddition.

Now, the flowvector has a length of 6 and the paddlingvector a lenght of 2.
Basic trigonometry says that the angle between the directionvector and the vector pointing south is $\alpha = \tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{6})=\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{3})$. Add a 180 degrees (for the missing half circle) and we have the angle of direction from the northern vector.

Now for where he lands:
The crossingtime is determined only by the paddling vector, since - assuming the river is 2000 ft at all points - we need to cross 2000 ft horizontally wise. Hence we determine the time needed for crossing 2000 ft while going 2 mph. A easy calculation (distance/speed) shows that we need 0,1893 hour for crossing the river. 
During this time he's moved 0,1893*6=1,1364 miles downward due to the flow of the river. This is the point where he will be when he has crossed.

Comment: Where he lands? On the other side of course. We have the angle; the time calculation is completely unnecessary.

Comment: The questions was: how far downstream from a point directly across the river will he land? The time calculation is one way. An other is to fit the vectors in the river. A other is with trigoniometry. But it is not completely unnecessary.

Comment: Beg to differ, but that wasn't the question. The question was "In what direction (measured clockwise from the north) will he actually be traveling? And how far downstream from a point directly across the river will he land?". Two part questions usually have a purpose in leading the student.